# TYPO3 v10 action controller and template inside subfolders

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

## Background

Until TYPO3 v9 it was possible to put controllers and fluid templates for the corresponding controller actions into subfolders like this:

**Classes/Controller/Product/CarController.php**

```php
namespace Vendor\MyExtension\Controller\Product;

class Car extends AbstractProduct {
   public function listAction(){
      // ...
   }
}
```

**ext_localconf.php**

```php
ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'MyExtension',
    'CarsPlugin',
    ['Product\Cars' => 'list'],
    []
);
```

Because of the controller name "Product\Cars" the relative fluid template path would be resolved to this:

`typo3conf/ext/my_extension/Resources/Private/Templates/Product/Cars/List.html`

In TYPO3 v10 this does not work anymore. I guess it's because now your supposed to give a fully qualified controller name like this:

**ext_localconf.php**

```php
ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'MyExtension',
    'CarsPlugin',
    [\Vendor\MyExtension\Controller\Product\CarController::class => 'list'],
    []
);
```

Now, TYPO3 only tries to relove this template:
`/typo3conf/ext/my_extension/Resources/Private/Templates/Car/List.html`

## Question

Is there a way for TYPO3 v10 to aknowledge the controller is in a subfolder and resolve the template, also checking the right subfolder?

It makes life that much easier when the file structure is the same. I also think that's especially important when representing complex hierarchies with domain models and controllers inheriting from parent classes, allowing the system to scale (think of Product/Airplane, Product/Ship etc.).

Comment: This might be a bug. I don't think that TYPO3 would want to break all extensions.

Comment: Well, it's also possible that it was never meant to work this way at all, but if have found no clue for this. Hm ..

Comment: Even if it was never the intended behavior, it would be a nice feature the way did it before. Maybe open a ticket on https://forge.typo3.org/projects/typo3cms-core/issues?

Comment: Good idea! I'll look into that and will post any results here.

Comment: Is the inconsistency here intentional? ("Car" vs "Cars", "Cars" vs "CarsController")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a long list of folders where to search for your layouts/templates/partials. Even in folders from other extensions. Higher key will be tried first

```
plugin.tx_myextension {
    view {
        templateRootPaths {
             10 = EXT:my_extension/Resources/Private/Templates/
             20 = EXT:my_extension/Resources/Private/Templates/Product/
        }
        partialRootPaths {
            10 = EXT:my_extension/Resources/Private/Partials/
            20 = EXT:my_extension/Resources/Private/Partials/Product/
        }
        layoutRootPaths {
            10 = EXT:my_extension/Resources/Private/Layouts/
            20 = EXT:my_extension/Resources/Private/Layouts/Product/
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm, I already fiddled around with the root paths but had no success. But I'll give it another try.

Edit: Actually, that is my current solution. It still does feel a bit too   ambiguous to me because of the overlaping directories where TYPO3 looks for the files. But I guess that's the way to go here.